# How can I force my leastsq function from scipy.optimize to be superior than each data points

Tags: python, numpy, optimization, scipy

I am currently trying to calculate a function to fit some data points using leastsq method from `scipy.optimize`.

The function I'm looking for is something like `f(x) = A * cos(b*x + c)`, with A, b, c the parameters i would to know.

My code is so far:

```
def residuals(p, y, x):
    A, b, c = p
    err = y - A * cos(b * x + c)
    return err


x = arange(-8, 9)
y = [0.060662282, 0.25381372, 0.357635814, 0.610186219, 0.689421037, 0.987387563,
 1.062490593, 1.09941534, 1.04789242, 1.05323342, 0.947636751, 0.929896615, 0.758757134, 0.572468578,
 0.422551093, 0.25694886, 0.029750763]

# The true parameters
A, b, c = 1.1, 0.2, 0.01
y_true = A * cos(b * x + c)

y_meas = array(y)

# initial guess
p0 = [1.0, 0.1, 0.05]
array(p0)

plsq = optimization.leastsq(residuals, p0, args=(y_meas, x))
print plsq[0]
```

this return as wanted :

```
[1.07861728 0.19353103 0.00361659]
```

This work well BUT i would like the function `f(x) = A * cos(b * x + c)`, computed with these parameters, to be superior to each data points.
In other words, I would like `f(xdata_i) > ydata_i` for all data points (xdata; ydata).

I have already tried to return a large value i.e `1.e6` in my residuals function if the `err > 0`. But the leastsq function seems to not appreciate it and return an non-understanding error message for me.

Comment: but then it is not a least square fit anymore is it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One approach is to formulate your problem from scratch as a constrained optimization problem and solve it via, e.g., scipy.optimize.minimize.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from scipy.optimize import minimize

# data set
x = np.arange(-8, 9)
y = np.array([0.060662282, 0.25381372, 0.357635814, 0.610186219, 0.689421037, 0.987387563,
 1.062490593, 1.09941534, 1.04789242, 1.05323342, 0.947636751, 0.929896615, 0.758757134, 0.572468578,
 0.422551093, 0.25694886, 0.029750763])


# define the LS fit as the objective function
def obj(z):
    a, b, c = z

    return (np.abs(y - a * np.cos(b * x + c))**2).sum()

# define constraint that the fit should be larger than the samples
def constraint(z):
    a, b, c = z

    return a * np.cos(b * x + c) - y

# required input for 'minimize' function
cons = ({'type': 'ineq', 'fun': constraint},)

z0 = (0,0,0) # provide an initial estimate of the parameters 
sol = minimize(obj, z0, constraints = cons)
A_opt, b_opt, c_opt = sol.x
print (A_opt, b_opt, c_opt)

#plot fit
x_range = np.linspace(-8,9,100)
plt.plot(x,y,'o')
plt.plot(x_range, A_opt * np.cos(b_opt * x_range + c_opt) )
```

> ```
> 1.15736059083 0.18957445657 0.0198968389239
> ```

[image]